# Why i Can't play clip on MediaElement?

Tags: silverlight

I using  controls:ChildWindow and on this childwindow i have MediaElement.
I set the MediaElement source to be some wmv file ( path of the clip is hard code ) and when the childwindow is up - i call 
MediaElement.Play

Code:

```
 mediaElement.Play();
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="mediaElement" Source="/Resource/movie.wmv" Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```

But i don't see anything - and i don't understand why.

The on MediaElement.MediaFailed i get exception '4001 AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR' and the movie.wmv location is on my local machine hardisk

Someone can help here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you detail the issue (what are you doing exactly... code & XAML excerpts for instance)

Comment: Does that movie play in Windows Media Player (for example)?

Comment: yes , win media player is playing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Source path is relative to the XAP file's directory (ClientBin). Are you sure the path is correct?

If that seems fine... the MediaElement errors are not always very informative, so maybe it is loading it but there is some problem with codecs (Silverlight only supports a partial set of the codecs Windows Media Player supports).

Comment: The path is fine, the file format is WMV - so i geusss the codecs are also fine.